# QT 5.01 QSqlDatabase connects, QSqlQuery executes, however nothing is found from the sqlite database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

As stated in the title, I have written code for QT to connect to a sqlite database.

```
bool FilterData::initDatabase(){
    QDir d;
    _db = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"));
    _db->setDatabaseName("OMBI.db");
    return _db->open();
}

void FilterData::loadFromDB(){
    if(initDatabase()){
    //set up the query
    QSqlQuery query(*_db);
    //vectors for storing results from the query
    QVector<QString>* measures = new QVector<QString>();
    QVector<QString>* title = new QVector<QString>();
    QVector<QString>* type = new QVector<QString>();

    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM measures");
    query.exec();


    while (query.next()) {
        measures->push_front(query.value(0).toString());
        title->push_front(query.value(1).toString());
        type->push_front(query.value(2).toString());
    }

    std::cout<<"Passed reading query results"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<measures->size()<<std::endl;
    emit measuresReady(*measures, *title, *type);
}
}
```

The database connects and opens just fine, however on testing the result of query.first(),
query.next(), query.isValid(), query.isActive(), and query.isSelect() are all false. OMBI.db  has been placed in the project folder for QT, as this is my first time working with QT I wasn't sure if this was correct protocol or not.

I've been trying to find a solution to this for far too long, and I have searched quite a bit, but to no avail. Hopefully some of you gurus can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

edit:

I've determined that exec() is failing and query.lastError() is reporting "No query unable to fetch row". I am now trying to determine what is causing the query to fail so miserably. I checked _db->lastError() but it was empty which I assume is a good thing.

Comment: Check if exec() returns true, and if not, what query.lastError() returns. (Btw: You're leaking the vectors, just create them on the stack)

Comment: I know about the leaks, however I require that the vectors are available until the slot is done with them so I just have it like this for the moment. 

I checked out the results of exec() and lastError(), exec was failing, and last error reported, "No query Unable to fetch row". I'm currently looking in to what the causes of this could be.

Comment: "I require that the vectors are available until the slot is done" - You're passing the vectors by value (or reference) anyway, I don't see any possible issue. when using measuresReady() in a direct connection (the default), all slots are executed before the vectors would be destroyed anyway, and if its used in a queued connection, the vectors would be copied even if passed by const reference.

Comment: Either way my questions is about getting the query to read from the database correctly, not about my leaking vectors. I'd appreciate it if you could lend any more advice towards that end.

Comment: Check that you're actually opening your existing OMBI.db. QSqlDatabase::open() won't fail if the file doesn't exist, but create a new OMBI.db file in place. In your code that would be the current working directory (QDir::currentPath()). Try with an absolute path instead, for testing.

Comment: Thank you Frank, hard coding in the path works. Now I just need to figure out how to get the project folders path from QT.